# IIS: Is it possible to completely ditch username + password and use certificates to authenticate?

Tags: iis

I want to setup a simple IIS site which will basically be the standard directory browsing in IIS (no .Net code).

Instead of using Windows Authentication, I would like to use a certificate to handle the authentication. My idea is any client system that has the public cert installed can browse this iis site, and others not.

Is this type of thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the following article for how to do this with IIS 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732996(WS.10).aspx